# How to get rid of Joomla Menu Overlay?

Tags: joomla

I'm currently working on a homework assignment adjusting the menus in Joomla, and I have the base of the assignment done, I just need to get rid of the menu I had there previously. It's overlaid on top and looks horrible.

This is what it looks like now: http://jesi-wu.com/sandbox/

I need the red header picture and all the text under it, to disappear. How do I do this?

**This is what I want removed (picture):** http://oi58.tinypic.com/n30t2r.jpg

-Alexis

Comment: Are you referring to the menu with the title "Student Menu"? All menus are modules, which you can manually disable in the Module Manager

Comment: No, I added a screenshot to my post (of what I'm trying to remove). Let me know if you can see it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just opened it in a different browser, chrome. And I think I see what you were seeing. I'm in firefox, but it shouldn't look like how it looks for me. Why is this....?

Comment: @Lodder I'm not sure if you got a notification of my replies

Comment: I would not recommend removing this. This is the component for your homepage. Instead, I would assign a single article to the homepage menu item and add your modules containing the pictures to them

Comment: How do I add those picture modules to my article? I just made an article as a placeholder, waiting for your reply

Comment: @Lodder what I don't understand, is why it looks alright in Chrome, but in Firefox, it looks horrible. I shouldn't have to even be messing with anything having to do with layout/menu/article stuff at all, right? Is this just a firefox issue? *note: I'm actively editing the site, you can check it to see my changes*

Comment: In your article, simply add `{loadposition XXX}`. Assign a custom position to your image module and then replace `XXX` that the name of that position.

Comment: The issue with the images currently is that you have assigned a set width to them so they overlap the container.

Comment: @Lodder Ok, that worked, but now there's duplicates because of the already existing modules on the left...but about the images, is there a way to set the images so that they automatically fit it's container?

Comment: The duplicates is a simple fix. Assign a different position to each module then use `{loadposition XXX}` and `{loadposition YYY}`. You need to make sure the position is a **custom** one. To do this, type the position name of your choice instead of selecting it from the dropdown menu